# jQuery - remove() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a script that places divs according the position of mouse on the body of a page. I have a button which says "Clear" and I want to use it to clear the divs created. How can I achieve that?

The script and source I have written:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bhaiya.js"></script>
        <button style="z-index: 2000;" class="clear" onclick="clear()">Clear</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(this).mousedown(function(e){
        $x = e.pageX;
        $y = e.pageY;

        $div = "<div class='theDiv' style='width: 250px; height: 150px; background-color:#e7e7e7; position: absolute; top:" + $y + "px; left:" + $x + "px;'>Hey</div>";
        $("body").prepend($div);
    });

    function clear() {
        $(".theDiv").remove();
    }

})
```

**jsFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/BpAYz/

**Any help would be appreciated :)**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inline html attribute event handlers can only call *global* functions. Your `clear()` function is *not* global because it is defined *inside* your document ready handler, so your `onclick="clear()"` can't find it. You need to either move the function outside the ready handler (making it global), or, better, bind the click with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $(this).mousedown(function(e){
        var $x = e.pageX;
        var $y = e.pageY;    
        var $div = "<div class='theDiv' style='width: 250px; height: 150px; background-color:#e7e7e7; position: absolute; top:" + $y + "px; left:" + $x + "px;'>Hey</div>";
        $("body").prepend($div);
    });

    $(".clear").click(function () {
        $(".theDiv").remove();
    });
});
```

Note also that I've added `var` in front of the variables in your mousedown handler: without `var` they become global variables, which just makes your code more error prone and hard to debug. (Unless you have a good reason why they *should* be globals?)

Comment: You're welcome. Note also `<button>` elements are submit buttons by default, and even though you don't have a form element or anything it's a good habit to use `type="button"` for buttons that are not intended to be submit buttons.

Answer (score 2):

The function `clear` should be in global scope. Otherwise give an id `button1` to the button and  add the function as the `click` event listener using jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/BpAYz/2/

Code:

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(this).mousedown(function (e) {
        if (!$(e.target).is("#button1")) {
            $x = e.pageX;
            $y = e.pageY;

            $div = "<div class='theDiv' style='width: 250px; height: 150px; background-color:#e7e7e7; position: absolute; top:" + $y + "px; left:" + $x + "px;'>Hey</div>";
            $("body").prepend($div);
        }
    });

    $(".clear").click(function () {
        $(".theDiv").remove();
    });

})
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <button id="button1" style="z-index: 2000;" class="clear">Clear</button>
</body>
```

I have just modified your code. Please use `var` keyword when declaring variables in a function.

Comment: but i already have added the class to that button? will it matter?

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Qn9yL/1/

You should attach to the click even of the button rather than using onclick.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(this).mousedown(function(e){
        $x = e.pageX;
        $y = e.pageY;

        $div = "<div class='theDiv' style='width: 250px; height: 150px; background-color:#e7e7e7; position: absolute; top:" + $y + "px; left:" + $x + "px;'>Hey</div>";
        $("body").prepend($div);
    });

    $('#clear').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".theDiv").remove();
    });

})
```

You also want to do the e.preventDefault(); to stop the event then bubbling up and creating a new div etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this:-

Clear

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(this).mousedown(function(e){
    $x = e.pageX;
    $y = e.pageY;

    $div = "<div class='theDiv' style='width: 250px; height: 150px; background-color:#e7e7e7; position: absolute; top:" + $y + "px; left:" + $x + "px;'>Hey</div>";
    $("body").prepend($div);
});

$(document).on("click", "button.clear", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
      $(".theDiv").remove();
})
```

})

Comment: this will add the click listener to all the buttons but i want the button with the class ".clear"

Comment: ok, but if I remove the "button" there will it make a problem?

Comment: You want create and open a div when someone mousedown on document?

Comment: stopPropagation() means stop any other event to be executed on the document, so it will only trigger the button event not the event on document when you click the button.

Comment: so then how will it click the button?

Comment: it will fire button event not the document

Answer (score -5):

This works with successive elements:

```
<style media="all">
.theDiv {
    display:none;
}
</style>
```